# Camel mina component dropping connections

Tags: sockets, apache-camel, mina

I am hoping that someone can help me with my problem.  I have a client application that sends XML messages to Camel.  I am using Mina2 v2.11.1 component in Camel as a endpoint to consume incoming XML.  I have no control over the client application and in most cases it requires a response to the request.  However there are a 2 messages that do not require a response.  I am finding that if I do not respond to every message then it will drop the connection, this is not desired as it needs to maintain the connection wether a response is sent or not.  I tried to set the **disconnectOnNoReply = false**, but it does not seem to be working as it continues to drop the connection.  My route in camel is setup as…

```
<camel:route> 
        <camel:from uri="mina2:tcp://10.5.60.60:9000?codec=#myDecoder&amp;disconnectOnNoReply=false"/> 
        <camel:bean ref="OutputProcessor"/> 
</camel:route>
```

Is it possible that I am doing something wrong in my encoder that is causing this to happen?  My encoder looks like…

```
@Override 
public void encode(IoSession is, Object o, ProtocolEncoderOutput peo) throws Exception { 


    if (o != null) { 
        IoBuffer ioBuffer = IoBuffer.allocate(512, false); 
        ioBuffer.setAutoExpand(true); 
        ioBuffer.setAutoShrink(true); 
        byte[] responseByteArr = (byte[]) o; 
        ioBuffer.put(responseByteArr); 
        ioBuffer.flip();    //Flip it or there will be nothing to send 
        peo.write(ioBuffer); 
        peo.flush(); 
    } 
}
```

If anyone can shed some light on this I would really appreciate it!

Thanks!

- Tim

Answer (score 0):

can you post the detailed configuration and code? Especially the #myDecoder and OutputProcessor bean.

I think something went wrong with those 2. Did you see some error in the log?